# Calling a method that modifies the value of another

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm creating an **Account** class as part of a Python lab assignment, and I'm not understanding the issue that's occurring. The constructor functions as it's meant to when I pass values to the other methods, but then I have to create a method called *withdraw*.

I've written it as it sounds like it should be, but I'm receiving an error which reads

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Account' and 'int'
```

The code segment for the method I created is below:

```
def withdraw(balance,withdrawn):
    self.__balance=balance-withdrawn
```

... and it's being called further below as follows:

```
acct1.withdraw(2500)
```

The exercise specifically asks to have this method, as well as a similar *deposit* method to be used. The best I can figure is that it's the setup of the method, rather than the way I'm calling it. Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'm still learning, so I apologize if I'm misusing any terms!

Comment: Define your withdraw function like this: `withdraw(self, balance, withdrawn)` Every function in a class will take the object as first parameter. acct1 will be passed as first parameter to withdraw function. So in your code `balance = acct1`

Comment: That hadn't even occurred to me. The way the description was written, withdraw wasn't included in the constructor (for understandable reasons) but somehow, to me, that translated to the inclusion of "self" to be unnecessary

Comment: Your functions don't have to be included in the constructor -- only member variables need to be included (except in some special cases when they don't).

Comment: If you could include the entire class definition in your question then you would have got better suggestions. danielunderwood has given you all the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues. I assume part of your code is like this:

```
class Account:
    # Rest of class
    def withdraw(balance, withdrawn):
        self.__balance = balance - withdrawn
```

You have a few problems:

1. `withdraw()` should take a parameter for class. This should be `self` for a member method like you have here or `cls` for a static method to actually access instance (or class) variables. This will be the first parameter for any class method. Your error is coming from the fact that `balance` is interpreted as an `Account`, which means `balance - withdrawn` tries to subtract an `int` from an `Account`. Such behavior is possible to obtain by overloading the correct [operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).
2. Your `Account` class has a `__balance` field, which should be used rather than passing a balance to the function. You could pass a balance for a static method, but that wouldn't be of much use.
3. Not really a problem, but you would probably want `__balance` to be accessible to inheritors, so you would use `_balance` for what would be equivalent to a protected fields in other languages.

You would end up with something like this:

```
class Account:
    # Rest of class
    def withdraw(self, withdrawn):
        # Withdraw (could also be self._balance -= withdrawn)
        self._balance = self._balance - withdrawn
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods should include self, try this:

```
def withdraw(self, withdrawn):
    self.balance -= withdrawn
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a class method, the current instance of Account (self) is being passed as the first argument to your function (balance).  TypeError is thrown because the withdraw function is attempting to subtract an Account object from an int.

Try this instead:

```
def withdraw(self, withdrawn)
    self.__balance -= withdrawn
```